# ASP.NET MVC Adding a Web Service Layer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2

I wanted to get some peoples opinions on adding a web serivce layer.  At my work, we want to start using web services to handle some of our operations.

**Our current project structure that we follow for our ASP.NET MVC apps:**

MVC App (View/Controller/ViewModel/Service Layer) --> BAL (Business Access Layer) --> DAL (Data Access Layer)

The MVC app, BAL, and DAL are separate assemblies.

There is a Domain (model) assembly as well that is shared among the MVC/BAL/DAL layers.

The plan is to create a web service that will handle all security functions.  This web service will be used by multiple web applications.  When we make changes to the Security Web service we only want to modify code in one place and not every web app.  So I'd prefer if the MVC project has nothing in it that is tied to a web service.

So I was thinking of adding a Web Service Layer between the BAL and DAL layers.

**So something like this:**

MVC project (View/Controller/View Model/Service Layer)

*calls*

BAL Layer (Handles caching / DB Transactions)

*calls*

Web Service Layer

*calls*

DAL Layer

What are your opinions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple thoughts.

You are putting your web service layer between you BAL and DAL.  This means everything will need to go through your web service, including functions which aren't related to security.  I think this is adding an additional layer of complexity.  If multiple websites are using the web service, create it as a stand along application/service.  Then you can call the service from the different layers of your application depending on what layer needs the service.  Generally you would create a Webservice wrapper with a clean interface so you can easily call the Web Service from your any layer in your application.

For the sake of discussion, lets say your web service handled validation of login and password of a user.   You can connect to your webservice wrapper directly in your MVC project to see if the user data is valid, then you can log them in if it is.  Later, if the user performs a function, and the business layer needs to check if the user has permissions, that layer can use the api wrapper which calls the api to see if user has permissions, and so on.

```
                                      MVC APP
                                      /    \
                                    BAL --> Web Service Wrapper
                                    /        \
                                  DAL        WCF WEB SERVICE
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I suppose in my case the BAL would serve as the wrapper for the WCF Web Service.  The web service layer would be between the BAL and DAL for functions requiring a web service.  The DAL assembly would exist in the Web Service deployment and in the MVC app deployment therefore not requiring everything to need a Web service.  Would that work?

Comment: Well anything will work.  It comes down to how pretty it is, how easy it is to maintain, change, and support.  If it gets too complicated it is hard to get team members up to speed. If you haven't read fowlers book on architecture this may be a good place to start to get up to speed on some pretty common and well known architecture and design patterns.  http://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311388344&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

As someone who supports an application that is ridiculously layered as so.

- GUI
- BAL
- DAL to WebService
- Webservice
- WebBAL
- WebDAL

I would suggest putting your GUI as close to your webservice as possible.

Comment: So you are suggesting something like: GUI(controller/view) --> Web Service --> BAL --> DAL  My concern with this is having the proxy class in the GUI assembly.  If I have to re-work the web service, I'll have to adjust the GUI (View/Controller) layer for wach app that uses it.  I'm new to web services so please let me know if I'm out to lunch.

Comment: You will not have to regenerate your webservice reference everytime you make a change to it. As long as you send all the required parameters and you do not change the existing fields on your return datatype, your web reference should still be able to function.